# Arrangement of 9 integers within a set of rules.

Tags: combinatorics

The integers 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13 are to be placed in alternating circles and squares with one number in each shape. {Starting and finishing with a square. 4 circles and 5 squares. A total of 9 shapes.}

Each integer must be used exactly once and the integer in each circle must be equal
to the sum of the integers in the two neighbouring squares. If the integer x is placed
in the leftmost square and the integer y is placed in the rightmost square, what is the
largest possible value of x + y?

I've managed to deduce that 13 has to be in a circle while 1, 2, and 4 have to be in a square. Getting a working arrangement is annoying though, kindly help.

Comment: Do you just need the result, or do you need it with proof?

Comment: with proof please.

Comment: Well, once you have an answer, maybe you can work backward to the proof. Of course, if you have any answer, then the same list in reverse order also works. (9, 10, 1, 5, 4, 6, 2, 13, 11)

Comment: That might work too.

Comment: I suspect there be be only two permutations satisfying this, one the reverse of the other

Comment: I iterated through all permutations in Python and returned all lists which satisfy the condition that circle values equal sums of neighboring squares. Only two lists popped up as satisfying that (the one I provided and its reverse). But I'm not a programmer by trade, so you may want to confirm that step.

Comment: @bangs: my bruteforce R attempt has the same  results, so we would have needed to make similar errors without communicating

Comment: Thanks. So it looks like we have the what(s). Now we need to know why this is the only one (up to reversing it).

Comment: So is there any method of  getting the same answer by logic?

Comment: One way to quickly cut down the options is to note that the total of the outer two circles must be congruent to $2$ modulo $3$ (by looking at the totals in the squares, the inner circles, and of all the numbers). Since neither of the outer circles can be $13$, there are only nine such pairs from the list; the largest of these, $(9,11)$, happens to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You noted that $1$, $2$, and $4$ must be in squares. These are also the three smallest numbers, so it would be nice to put them in the inner three squares (i.e., not in the two squares at the ends where you want to maximize the sum).  But $1$ and $2$ can't be in consecutive squares, since then you'd need a $3$ in the circle between these squares, and there is no $3$. So that suggests that the middle three squares be filled with $1$, $4$, $2$ in that order ($2$, $4$, $1$ would also work).

Then the middle $5$ entries would be $1,5,4,6,2$.

You noted that $13$ has to be in a circle, but it can't be directly to the left of $1$ because then you would need a $12$. So we try $13$ to the right of $2$.  This ends up giving an optimal sequence as $9,10 ,1,5,4,6,2,13,11$. (Of course the reverse of this sequence also works.)

Comment: Very simple and clear reasoning, super easy to follow. If I could, I'd upvote 10 times!